# Number of prime solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + 241$ such that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ is also prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

**Are there finitely or infintely many prime solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + 241$ such that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ is also prime?**

---

Richard Borcherd's [first lecture on algebraic geometry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZKDmTIFR7A) has, as an example, a birational correspondence between the unit circle and the y-axis that generates the Pythagorean triples.

It also has an algebraic characterization of Pythagorean triples.

The very first thing Borcherds did with $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is reduce it mod two, yielding:

$$ a^2 + b^2 \equiv_2 c^2 \implies \text{at least one of $a$ and $b$ is even if $\{a, b, c\}$ are coprime} $$

Borcherds uses this fact to characterize the Pythagorean triples algebraically, but reducing $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ mod two can also be used, with a little extra reasoning, to prove that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ has no prime solutions.

This got me interested in prime solutions to a different equation, shown below:

$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + 241 $$

A simple computer search suggests to me that there are infinitely many prime solutions to the above equation, *although I don't have a proof of this fact*.

However, solutions where $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ is *also prime* are much less common.

The only one I have found so far is:

$$ 11^2 + 31^2 = 29^2 + 241 $$

Since $ 11^3 + 31^3 + 29^3 $ is $55511$, which is prime.

Are there finitely or infintely many prime solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + 241$ such that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ is also prime?

Comment: Why in particular $241$?

Comment: It’s $11^2 + 17 ^2 - 13^2$. I wanted to guarantee at least one prime solution without the additional constraint.

Comment: You wrote $51$ instead of $29$

Comment: The first can be checked modulo 24 and the cubic can be checked modulo 18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some solutions:
$$ \matrix{
31 & 11 & 29 \cr
113 & 79 & 137 \cr
179 & 31 & 181 \cr
479 & 109 & 491 \cr
691 & 421 & 809 \cr
1279 & 827 & 1523 \cr
3023 & 2389 & 3853 \cr
3089 & 1399 & 3391 \cr
4229 & 131 & 4231 \cr
4339 & 3491 & 5569 \cr
}$$

The generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture implies that there are infinitely many solutions, but of course there's no proof.

For a bonus, here are two cases where the same number appears in two different solutions (not just by exchanging $p$ and $q$):

$$ \matrix{11551 & 3019 & 11939\cr
         39227 & 3019 & 39343\cr
         20509 & 20431 & 28949\cr
         97861 & 20431 & 99971\cr} $$

Comment: I don’t understand why this answer was downvoted twice when my question hasn’t been downvoted yet.

Comment: $31$ also appears in two solutions, which is neat.